# Why is NestJS logger not logging to terminal window?

Tags: nestjs

Currently I have the following code:

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
  logger: Logger;

  constructor(@InjectModel(Categories.name) private categoriesModel: Model<CategoriesDocument>) {
    this.logger = new Logger();
  }
...
```

In a method I then attempt to log:

```
getCategories({ text, first, page, hasType, parent }: GetCategoriesArgs) {
    this.logger.log('getCategories is triggered');
...
```

I don't get an error but I don't see the log message in terminal window.  Any ideas what I'm missing?  Also console.log() also doesn't appear.

Comment: does `console.log()` works?

Comment: @MicaelLevi no doesn't work.

Comment: then the issue isn't with the logger. Are you sure `getCategories` is being called? add `process.exit(4)` on it

Comment: It doesn't do anything.  I'm sure it's being called but I guess I have to dig deeper into this.  I see the resolver using the service and calling getCategories.  Ugh @MicaelLevi

Comment: have you tried with `process.exit(4)`. If `getCategories` is called, then your app will exit. If it's not exiting, then it's has not been called

Comment: Yes that's what I mean that process.exit(4) did nothing.  I'm gong to dig into this some more.  @MicaelLevi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240364/discussion-between-fabriciog-and-micael-levi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue - strangely, it appeared to be a cacheing issue. In my case I had to:

- delete the `/dist` folder and
- re-run `npm run start:dev`

Both `console.log(...)` and `this.logger.log(...)` instance I setup began working.